# How to map the database table into Hashmap in java code

Tags: java, regex, database

I am new to Java .I want to fetch the deatils of table and has to put it in hashmap .The database table has regex and value.In mapping I have to use Regex as key and Value is the corresponding regex value in table.

Please help on this.

Comment: What kind of technology are you planning to use? Plain JDBC? Some ORM framework (such as hibernate,...). Unfortunately (or luckily) there are multiple ways how to achieve something in java...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your regex is unique. because hashmap didn't take duplicate key values.
If you regex is unique then use Hashmap.

hashmap.put(db.getValue("regexkey"),db.getValue("value of regex.");

Comment: Shriram , Regex is unique always.Can you please elaborate in detail .Thanks in advance

Comment: you can get regex and store it as a key and value as value corresponding to the regex value.